# Can you use printf() and ncurses functions at the same time in C?

Tags: c, printf, ncurses

I am trying to print characters that are apart of the ASCII Extended table in ncurses, but printw() only supports printable characters that are 8-bits long. printf() however allows you to print characters above 8-bits. I want to use ncurses functions such as move() to move the placement of my cursor while also using printf() to print out the characters above 8-bits.

There are a few ways to solve this problem.

1) Somehow allow output while in ncurses mode for characters above 8-bits. This includes printw(), addch(), wprintw(), etc. I have asked questions on this topic before, with limited outcome. addch() in my Ubuntu compiler will print **some** ASCII values above 8-bits, but not all of them. Such functions as

```
addch(ACS_S1); addch(ACS_LANTERN);
```

doesn't print out the character, but rather prints out

```
⍰
```

2) Have printf() work simultaneously with ncurses functions like move() and init_color() so that I can print the characters above 8-bits. The reason I am having trouble with this is because when you use refresh() in ncurses, it clears the bottom screen replacing it with the window you are using. printf() either gets eradicated, or it won't work alongside move(). I think there might be a move function that moves cursors on specific windows, which in that case I might be able to move print, but I don't know the function nor the screen that printf resides on

I am using Ubuntu if that is a part of the problem. I don't think it is, but I am including it just encase.
Any help would be seriously appreciated.

Comment: You can use `printf()` at the same time as you use curses if you don't mind the mess that's created.  Curses thinks it has control over the screen and will be responsible for what appears.  Using `printf()` subverts that control and means curses gets confused.  All hell breaks loose.  Don't do it!

Comment: You'll need to work out how to handle multi-byte character sets with curses.  I've not done it using a standard curses, so I'm not sure what the rules are.  You'll need to find the manuals and read — probably rather carefully.

Comment: A Google search on 'ncurses unicode' looks informative; 'ncurses manual pdf' provides some information, but not so much on Unicode AFAICS.  You do need to be specific about which code set(s) you're working with.  You must know what your terminal expects; you must know what your ncurses supports.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your comment. Can you go a bit further into detail about the "code set(s)"? As for the "you must know what ncurses supports" I am well aware of that. I'd love to know every insignificant detail about it if I can, but I don't know where to go. My current knowledge is derived from a single website, some YT videos, and coming on here and asking those more experienced

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also in your first comment, you mention how you can use printf() with ncurses, but problems will occur. 2 questions. 1, how would you do it, and 2, what negatives would happen? Is it just troublesome to keep track of what's happening, or will mass errors take place that are impossible to track? Thanks again

Comment: What I mean about "code set(s)" is that you need to know whether your terminal is set up to display, for example, ISO 8859-15 (Western Europe including Euro symbol €) or UTF-8 or something else (ISO 8859-1 is common if you're in the USA; if you were on Windows, it might be CP1252).  Then you need to ensure that your program is configured to generate the right characters. The ISO 8859 and CP1252 code sets are single-byte code sets (SBCS). UTF-8 is an example of a multi-byte code set. A single character in UTF-8 can use 1 byte (eg letter A) or 2 bytes (eg Á) or 3 bytes (eg 式) or 4 bytes (eg ).

Comment: When curses refreshes the display, it won't know what was displayed via `printf()`, so that information will be lost.  Also, `printf()` will move the cursor, but curses thinks it knows where the cursor is, so it may end up making incorrect moves and showing information in unexpected places, etc.  As I said, it's a mess.  Don't do it!  Don't mix `printf()` with curses.  Do it all with curses.

Comment: Also during the refresh, curses may not erase the material printed by `printf()` as it doesn't know it's there.  You might have to do a force refresh to get rid of the mess (control-L or control-R in some programs).

Comment: I have no idea what "part of the ASCII Extended table" means, but ncurses supports UTF-8. You have just to set the right locale (eg. `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");`) and link with with "wide" version of the library (`-lncursesw`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's handled by the locales mechanism in Unix, and ncurses supports UTF-8 (and maybe other multibyte encodings, but there's very little reason to care about them in 2020).

Answer (score 2):

The question says:

> I am trying to print characters that are apart of the ASCII Extended table in ncurses, but printw() only supports printable characters that are 8-bits long.

Actually, ncurses's [***ncursesw***](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-ALTERNATE-CONFIGURATIONS) library (generally available since [2002](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-5.3.html)) handles multibyte characters (e.g., UTF-8), so `printw` handles strings like this:

```
char *foo = "  { 0x04a6, 0x30f2 }, /* kana_WO ヲ KATAKANA LETTER WO */";
printw ("%s", foo);
```

It won't interpret things like this as you might expect:

```
wchar_t foo = 0x04a6;
printw ("%c", foo);
```

since the underlying C runtime will insist that **`%c`** refers to a **`char`**, not **`wchar_t`**.  That all relies upon initializing the locale and using the right library.

It's certainly possible to mix stdio and curses, but that won't solve the problem you're asking about (and to do this successfully requires some work).  I've done this in [**`ded`**](https://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html#screenshots) (directory editor) for about 30 years, using part of the screen with curses, and part without.

Answer (score 0):

[irrespective of any confusion about charsets and Unicode support in ncurses, which exists and is perfectly usable]:

Instead of the curses functions you could use the lower level `tputs(.., putchar)` which, since it's using the stdio `putchar` to write the escapes, can be freely mixed with other stdio functions like `printf` or `fwrite`.

Example, compile it with `cc ... -ltinfo`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(void){
        char *cup;
        if(setupterm(0, 1, 0))
                errx(1, "setupterm failed");
        if(!(cup = tigetstr("cup")))
                errx(1, "no cursor addressing in terminal");
        tputs(tigetstr("smcup"), 1, putchar);

        tputs(tiparm(cup, 13, 13), 1, putchar);
        printf("HELLO");        /* or whatever you like */
        getchar();

        tputs(tigetstr("rmcup"), 1, putchar);
}
```