# The newline starts where the previus line ends in my hackertyper program

Tags: c++, string, ncurses, cout

I am working on this that shows a character when a key is pressed, like on the hackertyper website. But when another line is shown, it aligns it at the end of the previus line.

Here's how the lines should show:

```
Hello,          World!
This is a multi-line string.
```

Here's how they're shown:

```
Hello,          World!
                      This is a multi-line string
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <ncurses.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text = "Hello,          World!\nThis is a multi-line string.";
    // Initialize ncurses
    initscr();
    // Enables immediate input mode for capturing key presses in real-time.
    cbreak();
    // Disables showing your input characters, so it won't be gibberish
    noecho();

    for (char c : text) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            cout << c << flush;
        }
        else {
            getch();
            cout << c << flush;
        }
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try to use \n separately from string

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: something like str_part_1 then '\n' then str_part_2

Comment: Try `if (c == '\n') cout << '\r`;` after `getch();`.

Comment: This answers your question: [Can you use printf() and ncurses functions at the same time in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551647/can-you-use-printf-and-ncurses-functions-at-the-same-time-in-c).  There are [several duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cout+ncurses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding another if statement inside the else statement like this:

```
getch();
if (c == '\n') {
    cout << '\r';
}
cout << c << flush;
```